# Keyframe animation not working in Wordpress

Tags: html, css, css-animations, keyframe

I am trying to get an animation to run on a pseudo element in wordpress. I cannot work out why it is not working.

However, this animation is working in an CodeIgnite web correctly.

The code is:

CSS:

```
@keyframes fadeInLeft {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: none;
    transform: none;
  }
}

.fadeInLeft {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeInLeft;
  animation-name: fadeInLeft;
}
```

HTML: `<i class="fa-li fa fa-check-square-o wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay="1.5s" data-wow-duration="0.4s" ></i>`

Comment: Please create a [MRE] with all of the relevant code that shows the problem. There is no code here for keyframes or any sort of animation, and we can't fix a problem in code when we can't see it!

Comment: Did you call the wow library and the css animation library in file functions.php?

Comment: @EmAn yes the wow and animate libraries are called in the functios.php but the effect is not appear.

Comment: Write this <script>var wow = new WOW(); wow.init();</script> at the end of the page html

Answer (score 1):

### [`Animation property`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations)

Try to add animation duration that is

> `-webkit-animation: fadeInLeft 2s infinite;`

> `animation: fadeInLeft 2s infinite;`

```css
.fadeInLeft {
  -webkit-animation: fadeInLeft 2s infinite;
  animation: fadeInLeft 2s infinite;
}
@keyframes fadeInLeft {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: none;
    transform: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<i class=" fa fa-check-square-o wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay="1.5s" data-wow-duration="0.4s" ></i>
```

Comment: I added `infinite` to view on  demo :) hope this works

Comment: Yes i tried and this works, but the animate is not the same that i am looking for. I have a list with differents awesome icons and I want that the animate has a different delays for each of them. Would I have to do differents animate for each one?

Answer (score 0):

The `animation-duration` property defines how long time an animation should take to complete. If the `animation-duration` property is not specified (like on the code you provided), no animation will occur, because the default value is 0s (0 seconds).

You can read more on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/time)